# return JSON Object not reading

Tags: c#, json, ajax

i want to display my data and the number of rows in it.
i am returning json and there is some error there

```
    public JsonResult NewData()
    {
        List<mydatasample> mydata = new List<mydatasample>(); 
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 1 ", publisherName = " Name1 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 2 ", publisherName = " Name2 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 3 ", publisherName = " Name3 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 4 ", publisherName = " Name4 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 5 ", publisherName = " Name5 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 6 ", publisherName = " Name6 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 7 ", publisherName = " Name7 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 8 ", publisherName = " Name8 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 9 ", publisherName = " Name9 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        mydata.Add(new mydatasample { bookName = " Book 10 ", publisherName = " Name10 ", publishYear = 2018 });
        int rowcount= mydata.Count;

        return Json(new { mydata = mydata,rowcount = rowcount},  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is my ajax code.

the error is coming that it could not read

> e[j].bookName, e[j].publisherName, e[j].publishYear

to be specific my error is

> SomeActionMethod:59 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'bookName' of undefined
>        at Object.success (SomeActionMethod:59)
>        at fire (jquery-1.10.2.js:3062)
>        at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.js:3174)
>        at done (jquery-1.10.2.js:8249)
>        at XMLHttpRequest.callback (jquery-1.10.2.js:8792)

```
        $.ajax(
        {
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: hosturl,
            success: function (e)
            {

                var var1 = "<table>";
                var1 += "<tr> <th> Book Name </th> <th> Publisher Name </th> <th> Publish Year </th> </tr>";
                for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                {
                    //error is coming in this line
                    var1 += "<tr>" + "<td>" + e[j].bookName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publisherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                }
                var1 += "</table>";
                $("#t1").append(var1);

                var rowCount = $("#t1").find.length;
                for(var j = 1; j<e.rowcount; j++)
                {
                     var rowCount = $("#t1").find.length;
                     rowCount++;
                }
                var1 += "</table>";
                $("#t1").append(rowCount);
            },
```

Comment: try with e.mydata[j].bookName

Comment: If you add `console.log(e);` to the top of the success handler then look in the console it'll probably be a lot clearer to you why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You create a json object like this:

```
{  
    "mydata":[  
       {  
          "bookName":" Book 1 ",
          "publisherName":" Name1 ",
          "publishYear":2018
       },
       {  
          "bookName":" Book 2 ",
          "publisherName":" Name2 ",
          "publishYear":2018
       },
      ...
    ],
    "rowcount":10
}
```

You have to modify you loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < e.rowcount; j++) {
    var1 += "<tr>" + "<td>" + e.mydata[j].bookName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e.mydata[j].publisherName + "</td>" + "<td>" + e.mydata[j].publishYear + "</td>" + "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need to first convert the returned object to a javascript object since the default returned one will be a JSON string value, not an object that you can access via [].

consider the following snippet:

```
$.ajax(
        {
            cache: false,
            type: "GET",
            url: hosturl,
            success: function (e)
            {
              var data = JSON.parse(e);
              // now you can call something like this
              console.log(data[0].bookName);
            }
        });
```

And now you have an object that you can loop over and extract information from  as per your original question.